# Get new Wordpress slug from old wordpress slug

Tags: permalinks, shortcode, slug

I have implemented a shortcode called `post` which contains an attribute `src` which has link of an of page

```
[post src="http://www.listenmoneymatters.com/the-betterment-experiment/"]
```

Currently, this short code creates a fancy looking link based on the post's meta data:

```
// MORE INFORMATION LINK
add_shortcode('post', 'post_shortcode');
function post_shortcode($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "src" => '',
        "title" => '',
        "url" => '',
        "image" => ''
    ), $atts));

    $post_id = url_to_postid( $src );
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $post_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, array(150,150) );
    if($post->post_excerpt == '') {
        $post_description = text_limit($post->post_content, 175);
    } else {
        $post_description = $post->post_excerpt;
    }


    return '
        <a title="'.$post_title.'" href="'.$src.'" class="moreinfo">
            '.$post_thumb.'
            <h4>'.$post_title.'</h4>
            <p>'.$post_description.'</p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </a>';
}
```

The problem is, old occurrences of this shortcode links to posts which have had their permalink changed.

How can I look up the old post based on its old permalink and then make the short code display the link with the new permalink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we start may I just quickly mention that for the future it is easier to reference the post by its ID instead of the URL as this is going to stay the same when slugs change. Anyway as you already have this shortcode now we need another solution.

Your problem is that you need to find a post from its URL when the permalink changed. Fortunately the old slug is stored in `_wp_old_slug` in the `postmeta`table. So this is two steps:

### Get slug from URL

I assume that you didn't change the permalink structure, just the slugs. So here is the code to extract the slug from the URL:

```
$url ='http://www.listenmoneymatters.com/the-betterment-experiment/';
$url = explode("/",$url);   // Split URL at "/"
$url = array_filter();      // Remove empty array entries so get rid of last "/"
$slug = array_pop($url);    // Get last URL Segment
```

### Query posts for this slug

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'meta_key'         => '_wp_old_slug',
    'meta_value'       => $slug,
    'post_type'        => 'post',
));
```